# What is the best way stop Loop when viewDisappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

My aim is when viewDidLoad start (refresh) with frequency 0,8 sec AND after view disappear stop (refresh).

On viewDidLoad call (refres) function:

```
@proptery disAppear;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSLog(@"TeklifVer-viewDidLoad()");
   self.disAppear = NO;
   [self refresh];    
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   NSLog(@"viewDiddisappear"); 
   self.disAppear = YES;
}
```

on (refresh) function call (refresh) : `[self performSelector:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];` if not disAppear.

```
- (void) refresh
{
    NSLog(@"refresh");

    ...
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary * responseDictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

        if (!self.disAppear) {
            ...
            TeklifVerModel * teklifVerModel = [[TeklifVerModel alloc] initWithDictionary:responseDictionary];

            //init labels
            ...

            @try {
                if (teklifVerModel.ihaleStatus == 2) {
                    self.nextPage = true;
                } else if (teklifVerModel.ihaleStatus == 5) {
                    self.ihaleListesi = true;
                }
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", exception);
            }
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];

    if (self.nextPage) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        IhaleViewController * ihale = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ihaleViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:ihale animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (self.ihaleListesi) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        IhaleListesiViewController * ihaleListesi = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ihaleListesi"];
        [self presentViewController:ihaleListesi animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if(!self.disAppear) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
    }
}
```

Logs

```
2015-07-03 15:51:24.918 uztb[729:129628] refresh
2015-07-03 15:51:25.189 uztb[729:129628] viewDidDisappear
2015-07-03 15:51:25.720 uztb[729:129628] refresh
2015-07-03 15:51:26.522 uztb[729:129628] refresh
2015-07-03 15:51:27.324 uztb[729:129628] refresh
2015-07-03 15:51:28.127 uztb[729:129628] refresh
```

My Problem is when viewDisapper still some (refresh) executed. Sometimes (refresh) never stops. So when this view loaded again more than one (refresh) thread executed

Question: What is the best approach to stop (refresh) thread when viewDisappear?

Answer (score 3):

Try and call the `cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget` method in your `viewDidDisappear`.
[More info.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/index.html)

Comment: [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelector:@selector(refresh) target:self argument:nil]; did not stop anything. What am i missing ?

Comment: @AliNadi could you please update your code with the newly entered line ?

Comment: i removed if(!self.disAppear) control after that. Do i still need it ?

Comment: No you don't need this flag anymore. Could you please update your code above so that we can check again ?

Comment: @AliNadi Why didn't you use the `cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget` method ?

Comment: I tried '[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];' still never stops.